# why is s:mvcUrl function returning different results on different views?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm calling the function `mvcUrl()` on two different JSP files. On the first file, it is returning the expected result, but in the second one, it is returning the URL with the path of this JSP on the middle of it.

I'm using Spring MVC 4.1.0, Spring Security 4.0.0 on Apache Tomcat 9.

I've been looking for someone that had this issue for hours but I can't find anything similar to it. I've already tried different Spring Security Rules, changing the action name on the controller, giving an explicit name for the method but nothing works.

My Spring Security configuration:

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/usuarios/**").hasRole(TipoUsuario.ADMIN.toString())
                .antMatchers("/contas/").hasRole(TipoUsuario.ADMIN.toString())
                .antMatchers("/contas/form").hasRole(TipoUsuario.ADMIN.toString())
                .antMatchers("/contas/cadastro").hasRole(TipoUsuario.ADMIN.toString())
                .antMatchers("/contas/fechar").hasRole(TipoUsuario.ADMIN.toString())
                .antMatchers("/contas/fechar/confirmar").hasRole(TipoUsuario.ADMIN.toString())
                .antMatchers("/relatorios/cliente").hasRole(TipoUsuario.ADMIN.toString())
                .antMatchers("/movimentacoes/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/", false)
                .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/acessoNegado");
    }
```

The method I'm calling:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/movimentacao")
public class MovimentacaoController {

@RequestMapping(value="/cadastrar", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView cadastrarMovimentacao(CadastroMovimentacaoWrapper wrapper,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @AuthenticationPrincipal Usuario usuarioLogado) {
    [...]
}

}
```

the one that is working correctly:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>


<h1>${s:mvcUrl('MC#cadastrarMovimentacao').build() }</h1>
```

the one that isn't:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> 


<h1>${s:mvcUrl('MC#cadastrarMovimentacao').build() }</h1>
```

I'm expecting the `mvcUrl` function to return something like `localhost:8080/movimentacao/cadastrar` (which is exactly what I'm getting on the first JSP) but, I'm getting something like `localhost:8080/WEB-INF/views/colaborador/conta.jsp/movimentacao/cadastrar` (on the second JSP)

Observation: 'WEB-INF/views/colaborador/conta.jsp' is the path to the view that is rendering this code that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thoroughly analyzing the code I found out this behavior happens due to the ModelAndView object in the controller of the JSP that is rendering the page with the `mvcUrl` call.

On the working case, I was returning this instance of ModelAndView object: `modelAndView = new ModelAndView("admin/detalhe/conta");`
On the other case the instance was `modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/colaborador/conta");`

**I removed the extra slash at the beginning and the error ceased.**

Now, I wonder why it finds the file correctly but interferes on the other method.